# JQuery button clicks via mouse not working in Chrome due to touchscreen and mouse conflict

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, touch

I am using a plugin, called smoothzoom.js. Recently I have noticed that it does not work correctly on the Chrome browser. The zoom buttons and the ability to drag the zoomed image around do not work. The demo site for the plugin also does not work.

http://vectorflower.com/preview/smooth_zoom/

My investigations lead me to believe that because my new laptop is touch screen, it has highlighted the problem to me. There is a conflict between touch and mouse actions. Touching the screen works where using the mouse does not.

The plugin still works correctly on IE and mobile browsers.

Does anyone have any experience of this who could provide a solution?

Could this be patched using the jQuery Mobile events such as vmousedown?

Comment: Everything is working for me in Chrome.

Comment: you can click on the zoom buttons and drag the image in the viewer?

Comment: Yes sir. I can use all functionality. Using Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.111 m

Comment: I'm using the same. If I load in incognito mode will that have the same effect as clearing cookies?

Comment: I believe it does. Try - in addition to that - perhaps Logging out of Google account in the browser, and clear everything when it asks you. This has saved me from some headache in the past.

Comment: using the mouse wheel and double clicking on the image zooms in, however none of the buttons work or dragging around the image

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is working good for me on Chrome, Try to clear your cache on chrome !

Comment: using the mouse wheel and double clicking on the image zooms in, however none of the buttons work or dragging around the image

Comment: Ok, start by closing your chrome browser ... after that open private window as follow : http://img.wonderhowto.com/img/70/62/63439021050029/0/private-browsing-for-firefox-chrome-internet-explorer.w654.jpg

and try again

Comment: Can I ask, Do you have a touch screen PC? I have had just read the notes on the vendor site and see there is some sort of conflict with touch screen devices. Mine is touch screen.

Comment: No, My screen is not a touch screen!

Comment: Perhaps this is the problem

Comment: This is weird ... however I dont think there is a relation with your problem ... have you tried what I suggested ?

Comment: I have tried everything. suggested on the page. I have a colleague next to me who has also tried on their touch screen laptop, and it does not work either.

Comment: Ok, so perhaps, as you said, it is the cause of the problem :( .. first time I heard about it ! thanks for reporting!

Comment: This issue seems to only affect touchscreen laptops.

Answer (score 0):

Having read the comments on the plugin vendor site, disabling touchscreen support on chrome://flags solves the problem, but this is not a solution for the every day user of sites containing the plugin.